# Redirecionamento https sem www com apache e startssl

Tags: apache, ssl

É uma coisa um pouco complicada... Mas o problema é simples. Uso o certificador gratuito da *StartSSL* e como é gratuito posso criar chaves apenas para meu domínio e um subdomínio.

Acontece que substituí e acabei perdendo a chave *(.key)* responsável pelo subdomínio *"www"*. Tenho outras chaves, por exemplo, para "painel.site" e ".site", "servidor.site" e ".site"... E assim vai.

Se conectar *http:// site* ou *www.site* ele redireciona para *https:// site.com*.
Mas eu queria que(funcionava antes de perder o *.key*) o *www* no *https* também fosse para *https:// site.com*.

O redirecionamento dentro do apache não funciona, pois antes dele redirecionar tem que trocar as chaves, o que me leva a um erro de certificado. Pensei em ao invés de usar um *cname www* no *dns* eu usar como subdomínio redirecionado  pra algum diretório, por exemplo *.com/redir/* - uso o *domain.com* - mas não deu certo.

Olha... não sei se expliquei pouco ou acabei atrapalhando explicando muito... mas é simples... Direcionar *www* seguro para *dominio.com* sem erro de *ssl*.

Posso gerar chaves mas continuaria o erro. só tenho o arquivo *.crt* original.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?? Terei de pagar a revogação???

Comment: Se por "perdeu" você quer dizer "pode ter sido roubado", então o jeito é revogar, pois senão alguém pode fazer mau uso dele. Caso contrário, não há necessidade de revogar. Você pode gerar um *novo* certificado para esse subdomínio, não? (você teria de fazer isso quando o antigo expirasse de qualquer forma, com certeza eles oferecem essa opção) Tentar "driblar" a situação, creio que é inviável, pois o browser assume que se um usuário digitou `https://www.site` ele quer se comunicar de forma segura com o `www` - e não vai aceitar nada diferente disso vindo de um meio inseguro.

Answer (score -1):

É apenas tirar o www e **também** o http. Exemplo: meudominio.com

Comment: Tirar de onde? Mesmo que não tenha nenhum link [interno] usando `http://www` os usuários sempre podem digitar isso na barra de endereço do browser, não? Caso isso aconteça, ou algum link externo aponte pra esse endereço, o alerta de segurança será exibido.